# Is there a loading spinner/indicator for webview content in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm making a VSC extension that uses a webview, I made a loading spinner for the web view (just html and css) but was wondering if there is some kind of official loading spinner that should be used.

In the extension webview for example when content is loading - like a change log - several circles appear animated in a line. How can I use this spinner in my own webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to this animation:

[image: Loading animation]

Then it's achieved with a `<div>` holding a `.loading` class. And here's the CSS related to that class:

```css
.extension-editor>.body>.content.loading {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='575' height='6px'%3E %3Cstyle%3E circle { animation: ball 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 1.000, 1.000, 0.000) infinite; fill: %23bbb; } %23balls { animation: balls 2.5s linear infinite; } %23circle2 { animation-delay: 0.1s; } %23circle3 { animation-delay: 0.2s; } %23circle4 { animation-delay: 0.3s; } %23circle5 { animation-delay: 0.4s; } @keyframes ball { from { transform: none; } 20% { transform: none; } 80% { transform: translateX(864px); } to { transform: translateX(864px); } } @keyframes balls { from { transform: translateX(-40px); } to { transform: translateX(30px); } } %3C/style%3E %3Cg id='balls'%3E %3Ccircle class='circle' id='circle1' cx='-115' cy='3' r='3'/%3E %3Ccircle class='circle' id='circle2' cx='-130' cy='3' r='3' /%3E %3Ccircle class='circle' id='circle3' cx='-145' cy='3' r='3' /%3E %3Ccircle class='circle' id='circle4' cx='-160' cy='3' r='3' /%3E %3Ccircle class='circle' id='circle5' cx='-175' cy='3' r='3' /%3E %3C/g%3E %3C/svg%3E") 50% no-repeat;
}
```

You can certainly re-use this background code to some `.loading` class that you'd use in your webview to render the same effect